# the difference and similarity between 'subspace embedding' and ' dimension reduction'

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, metric-spaces

Can someone show me the difference and similarity between 'subspace embedding' and 'dimension reduction' using the mathematical definition? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide links to definitions for those terms (from wikipedia, for example). It is possible that these ideas go by different names.

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom Thanks. For the 'subspace embedding', you please refer to the 1st page of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.3280v1.pdf, where $\Pi x$ can be regarded as a dimension reduction with length well preserved. However, I remember that $\Pi x$  without the probability that the length  should be preserved, can also be regarded as 'subspace embedding'. This is correct?